# Convert string of table name type in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looping through all the table names in database and printing them with their data. But, I want to know how can I convert a variable name which stores table name to actual table type i.e. it can be considered as a table instead of a string. Here is a example:

```
<% ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table| %>
    <% table.column_names.each do |column| %>
            <%= column %>
    <% end %>
```

Here table becomes a variable but its value is actual table name obtained from database. I am trying to do the `rails db` command, for eg:

```
> User.column_names
```

Comment: @deefour not sure how thats a duplicate though? can you help with my question?

Comment: You're asking how to convert a table name - your `table` variable, into it's related ActiveRecord model: "how can I convert a variable name which stores table name to actual table type". That is exactly what the question I linked to answers. Call [constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) on the result to get the class - then you can call `column_names` as you are above.

Comment: Though I believe this is a duplicate, I'll also mention I didn't anticipate my single vote would close out this question. I was merely suggesting it was a duplicate. I think I recently answered enough questions in the `ruby-on-rails` tag to have the ability to close duplicates on my own. There doesn't appear to be a way to undo it.